# Calling A Public Method Causes NullPointerException - Android

Tags: java, android

Ahm, Hey everyone, I just want to ask what is the problem in the program I am creating. Here is the Snippet Codes

**PlayActivity.class**

```
//more codes here
 public void stFLabel(int numFace, Context ct) {

    try {
        if(numFace > 0)
            faceLebel.setText("Face Hint : I See You Human");
        else
            faceLebel.setText("Face Hint : Where Are You?");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "stFLabel Has Error");
        }
    }
//more codes here
```

****CameraPreview.class****

```
//More codes
...
PlayActivity pacT = new PlayActivity();
...
//More Codes
..
public void pausy(int numFace) {
pacT.stFLabel(numFace, mContext);
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
04-05 16:11:26.150: D/FaceDetection(27929): face detected: 1 Face 1 Location X: 65Y: -1
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at com.delihente.faceplay.PlayActivity.stFLabel(PlayActivity.java:90)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at com.delihente.faceplay.CameraPreview.pausy(CameraPreview.java:62)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at com.delihente.faceplay.CameraPreview$1.onFaceDetection(CameraPreview.java:53)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
04-05 16:11:26.150: W/System.err(27929):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 16:11:26.150: D/(27929): stFLabel Has Error
```

**MORE INFO :**

```
PlayAcvitiy.class extends Activity (Main Class)
CameraPreview.class - The camera preview class provided by google android development
faceLebel = TextView on PlayAcvitiy.class
mContext = PlayActivity.class Context
```

I want to know what is causing the NullPointerException (A Fix will be Better),
I have read almost 3 pages of google search about my problem but none of it has helped me.
and also, please don't mention to change the method to static because It cannot be because it changes the TextView Label when the CameraPreview.class detects/Undetects Faces..
Thanks in Advance!

EDIT : I have also read so many related questions here, but none of them seem to help

EDIT 2 : **Problem Solved**, thanks to all, specially to PrafulBhatnagar, I have learned that Using a method in the Main Activity needs a reference to its context. Thanks Everyone!

Comment: try `((PlayActivity)mContext).stFLabel(numFace, mContext);`... Assuming `mContext` stores the reference to the `PlayActivity`

Comment: You are trying to call/get something from a object that is null. It could be "faceLebel" that is null when you are calling setText(). Debug it

Comment: Is 'faceLebel' properly declared? Seems like the only thing it can be thrown on.

Comment: it's either "faceLabel" that is null or the pacT is being nulled somewhere between the new object and the function call.

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar, Great Fix! Thanks for the quick reply, anyway, can I know what kind of method is that? (Android Programming Newbie, but has the habit of testing all sorts of experiments)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for the answers!

JohnSnow - how can be a TextView be null?
Skepi - Declared? yes, upon the creation of PlayActivity.class

Comment: @ElPadrinoLucioPilar _ You have declared TextView in  PlayActivity but you are accessing this TextVIew in CameraPreview.class which has not a reference of that TextView. So you have to use reference (Context) of PlayActivity to access TextView in CameraPreview.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android you should never create Activity object on your own..

When you launch application from app tray the System creates Object for your Launcher `Activity` and launch it.. We use `startActivity()` if we want to go from one screen to another, here again system creates the object of `Activity`..

So in general the system creates object of Activity and calls its life cycle method like `onCreate(), onStart()` etc.. And we use these lifecycle callback to initialize/de-initialize state of the `Activity`..

The problem in your code is that you are trying to create `Activity` object on your own; so now there are two instances one created by system where all the state has been initialized and one created by your code where the state on the class has not been initialize since there was no call to lifecycle method hence the `NullPointerException`.

You can use the following code to fix this error:

`((PlayActivity)mContext).stFLabel(numFace, mContext);`... Assuming `mContext` stores the reference to the `PlayActivity`

Hope it Helps..

Answer (score 1):

The only reason of `NullPointerException` is,

`faceLebel` is **Null** inside `stFLabel()` method.

Just be sure your `faceLebel` is use the same id which has your current activity layout xml has.

Also , make sure you have declared `setContentView(<R.layout.xml_File_Name>)`; in `oncreate()` of Activity after `super.onCreate().`

**Update:**

I have a doubt of calling your method `stFLabel()` in **CameraPreview.class**,. Because you can not make constructor of Activity like, `PlayActivity pacT = new PlayActivity();`

You have to use Context of Activity to call this method.

Comment: Oh I See, so that is the reason, :).
I guess I really need to do more self-study android programming. the One you said, "Use Context of Activity to call this method", I really don't know how to do that, But i guess that would be @PrafulBhatnagar's answer (If im not mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `faceLeble` is initiated like below before calling set lable

```
faceLebel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewId);
```